# PyQt: QAxBase.dynamicCall overloaded with list as arguments

Tags: pyqt, activex

calling QAxBase.dynamicCall like this works:

```
my_comp.dynamicCall("MyMethod(const QString&, int, bool)", "test", 2, False)
```

however, using the overloaded call (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaxbase.html#dynamicCall-2) doesn't:

```
my_comp.dynamicCall("MyMethod(const QString&, int, bool)", ["test", 2, False])
```

It gives an Error: ... Non-optional parameter missing

The overloaded call expects a `QList<QVariant>` in Qt. Is the list I've provided mapped automatically to a `QList<QVariant>` by SIP? Can I create it manually?

As I've got 18 args I need to use the overloaded call.

EDIT: I've also converted the args explicitly to a QVariant like this, but the same issue.

```
args = ["test", 2, False]
q_var_args = [QVariant(arg) for arg in args]
my_comp.dynamicCall("MyMethod(const QString&, int, bool)", ["test", 2, False])
```

Cheers,

Jan

Comment: Shouldn't the edited part be like `my_comp.dynamicCall("MyMethod(const QString&, int, bool)", q_var_args)`? In that code you are still sending `non-QVariant` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a fixed parameter followed by an unpacked list of parameters:

```
 params = ["test", 2, False]
 my_comp.dynamicCall("MyMethod(QString, int, bool)", *params)
```

Comment: Unfortunately Qt doesn't accept more than 8 paramters this way [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaxbase.html#dynamicCall). My ActiveX method expects 18 (it's a transformation).